# I have trouble trying to move an oval with TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i begin to use TKinter and i try to make multiple boucing balls as a training exercise. When i create an unique oval and make it move, everything works but when i create a Ball class with a move method in it, the ball doesn't move at all. I receive no error message but it refuse to move.

```
"""
Initialisation
"""
from tkinter import *
import time

w_height    = 600
w_width     = 800
xspeed      = 10
yspeed      = 10

window = Tk()
window.geometry ("{}x{}".format(w_width, w_height))
window.title("Bouncing Balls")
canvas = Canvas(window, width = w_width - 50,height = w_height - 50, bg="black")


"""
If i create the ball like that and make it move it works fine
"""

ball1 = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 50, 50, fill ="red")
while True:
    canvas.move(ball1, xspeed, yspeed)
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
"""
But if i try to create the ball using a class it doesn't work anymore...
"""

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, r):
        canvas.create_oval(posx-r, posy-r, posx+r, posy+r, fill ="red")

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        canvas.move(self, dx, dy)

ball1 = Ball(50,50,10)

while True:
    ball1.move(xspeed, yspeed)
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

I tought it would give the same result but in the first case the ball moves and in the second it doesn't and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `canvas.create_oval()` function returns an object that can be then moved my called `canvas.move(object, ...)` function. But as you can see you are passing `self` in the class method `move`.

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    canvas.move(*self*, dx, dy)
```

This is the instance of the class Ball, in this case `ball1` variable, that you defined(actually reassigned) by doing `ball1 = Ball(50, 50, 10)`.

To get this working change your class to this.

```
class Ball:

    def __init__(self, posx, posy, r):
        self.ball = canvas.create_oval(posx-r, posy-r, posx+r, posy+r, fill ="red")

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        canvas.move(self.ball, dx, dy)
```

> Here you define a class field that will get what returns `canvas.create_oval() function and then use it to move the object.`